# Extract an entire Python dictionary from a list and export to csv

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a dictionary embedded within a list in Python. I'd like to extract just the dictionary and then export it to a csv file, with each column representing a unique dictionary key (i.e. Date). For example, here is a (small snippet) of the embedded dictionary I have:

```
[[{'Date': '2018-069', 'Title': 'The Effect of Common Ownership on Profits : Evidence From the U.S. Banking Industry', 'Author': 'Jacob P. Gramlich & Serafin J. Grundl'}, {'Date': '2018-068', 'Title': 'The Long and Short of It : Do Public and Private Firms Invest Differently?', 'Author': 'Naomi E. Feldman & Laura Kawano & Elena Patel & Nirupama Rao & Michael Stevens & Jesse Edgerton'}]]
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: `l[0][0]` ? then turn it to csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below should do, using `DictWriter` as Patrick mentioned in the comments

```
import csv


def main():
    '''The Main'''

    data = [[{'Date': '2018-069', 'Title': 'The Effect of Common Ownership on Profits : Evidence From the U.S. Banking Industry', 'Author': 'Jacob P. Gramlich & Serafin J. Grundl'}, {'Date': '2018-068', 'Title': 'The Long and Short of It : Do Public and Private Firms Invest Differently?', 'Author': 'Naomi E. Feldman & Laura Kawano & Elena Patel & Nirupama Rao & Michael Stevens & Jesse Edgerton'}]]
    with open('sample.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = data[0][0].keys()
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data[0]:
            writer.writerow(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```